# Best way to split a list into start, middle and End

Tags: c#, arrays

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me the best approach to splitting a list which contains text data. The current program reads a text file and stores the values to a list, the number of lines/data is not constant so i wanted to split the full list in percentage if that's possible for example the first 15% = start, the next 70% = middle and finally the last 15% = end.

- Additional info = the program monitors a running session hence the start(warm up) middle (main run) and end (cool down) aspect to the question. Ultimately i want to be able to incorporate this into a zedgraph and show my performance in the running sessions.

I am having a problem researching this and putting it into computational terms, i do appreciate your knowledge and time.

Comment: just create a for block and have your controls for list.Count() / 100 * 15 etc.

Comment: I tried something similar, however I could only get the first percentage from the start of the list, so the first 15% was achieved however the middle section also read from the first list (line 1) too as opposed to from the 15% if that makes sense, thanks for the response btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a little Linq:

```
var index1 = (int) Math.Round(array.Length * .15);
var index2 = (int) Math.Round(array.Length * .70);

var start = array.Take(index1);
var middle = array.Skip(index1).Take(index2 - index1);
var end = array.Skip(index2);
```

See [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) and [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) methods.

You could also use the [`ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) class:

```
var index1 = (int) Math.Round(array.Length * .15);
var index2 = (int) Math.Round(array.Length * .70);

// Replace T with your class name
var start = new ArraySegment<T>(array, 0, index1);
var middle = new ArraySegment<T>(array, index1, index2 - index1);
var end = new ArraySegment<T>(array, index2, array.Length - index2);
```

Comment: Oh great, thanks for response, this is what i have been trying to do for the past seven hours :), I think i need to revise my Linq, ill accept when it allows me in a moment.